# JQuery JEasyUI treegrid or FancyTree but responsive for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, treegrid, fancytree, jquery-easyui

I'm searching the same functionality as fancytree but as it uses right click is a no-go for mobile, can i put buttons in the side instead of using the context menu for mobile devices?

What other alternative it is for fancytree? can i put buttons to the actions of fancytree and Jeasyui treegrid to customize layout?

Comment: Hey have you got any solution for this?

Comment: Added an answer after a lot of research, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research i found that TableSaw was the closest to the goal of responsive tables, allowing to stack tabular data when in small screens: https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw

Honorable mentions:

- FooTable: Seems like TableSaw but more customizable, as well as a little harder to set up. https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable
- FancyTree: Overkill, it's too op (Over Powered), use only if complex apps, simple responsive ones will reach bottleneck faster if not setup with care as it has large amount of features. https://github.com/mar10/fancytree